# What does he mean, "you people"?

Tags: dialogue, tropic-thunder

In the legendary movie *Tropic Thunder* the following conversation takes place:

> "What do you mean, 'you people'?"
>
> "What do YOU mean, 'you people'?"

**But what DOES he mean, 'you people'?**

Comment: I never get tired of this scene, it's superb!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a race gag. Tugg Speedman is referring to the *group collectively* as being unadventurous, however Kirk Lazarus gets super-defensive about being referred to as "you people" (e.g. he implies that Tugg meant "you **black** people...").

Meanwhile Alpa Chino steps in to take umbridge at Kirk getting upset over Tugg's perceived 'racist' language given that **he isn't actually black** but has merely had a skin darkening treatment.

We're laughing at three things here;

- Kirk being so "in character" that he's started to become a stereotypical [angry black man](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AngryBlackMan), acting super-sensitively toward perceived racism, even where it's clear that none exists.
- Alpa's disgust at the fact that Kirk (a white man) is mistakenly accusing people of racism.
- Tugg's discomforture at being accused of racism (by someone white).

Comment: I don't think Alpa Chino came in to defend Tugg's comment, simply to take offense at Lazarus's appropriating the black struggle.

Comment: @avnershahar-kastan - That's an equally valid way of looking at it. I personally think it's a mix of both.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - Better now? I've tried to reflect both elements.

Comment: It's also a reference to an actual event. 1992 presidential candidate Ross Perot used the term "your people" several times during a speech to an NAACP meeting. It did not go over well. If the link here goes stale, web search for "Ross Perot" and "you people"; it won't be tough to find. 
http://www.nytimes.com/1992/07/12/us/the-1992-campaign-racial-politics-perot-speech-gets-cool-reception-at-naacp.html?pagewanted=all

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - I'm not so sure. Even a cursory google search reveals multiple uses of the phrase that significantly pre-date 1992; http://www.nytimes.com/1986/10/24/us/study-finds-racism-at-mit.html

Comment: @Richard A cursory Google search doesn't convey the national reaction very well. The Perot incident was the first time I noticed the phrase getting anything like that much attention. It made quite an impression on a lot of people. It was the first thing I thought of when I saw the movie and I'll bet that was true for anyone else who was paying attention during the '92 campaign period. But...just my memories and my opinion. :)